# VF page to Standard Object Page

Tags: visualforce

I am looking for help on below.

I have a VF page get triggered from Task item on click of a button. I want that when job is done on VF page and when a button is clicked, it should go back to respective lead page and not on task page.

I have tried, but this is not coming up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The link below has details on opening standard page from Inline VF page.

http://blog.shivanathd.com/2013/01/ReloadStandardPageFromInlineVF.html